# Does the transformed term has meaning in Calculus Average Value?

Tags: calculus

If you calculate the average temperature of a given day, but time series data is measured as a continuous function, the initial idea is to average the temperature of each hour.  Then applying the limitation theory gives us this:

$$T = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)$$

But we consider $n$ here comes from $n = \frac{b-a}{\Delta x}$ or initially $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$

Then the equation is transformed to $T = \frac{\Delta x}{b-a} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)$ or $T = \frac{1}{b-a} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)*\Delta x$, it is now transformed to integration.

But how should we interpret the term $\frac{1}{b-a}$ here?

Is that just re-deformation or should I care about the meaning of each term?  Please help

Comment: If temperature time series data of a given day can possibly be measured continuously is highly disputable. Back to math: what is to you the average of the function $f(x)=x$ on $[0,2]\,?$

Comment: Rectangular height of which the area is the same as the T(x) on x-y axis

Comment: Excellent. Will $\int_a^b T(x)\,dx$ give us that average when we do not divide by $b-a\,?$

Comment: So we should interpret geometrically, knowing integration part first (sigma notation reminds us Rieman Sun), then get it from $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)$ and naturally separate $\frac{\Delta x}{b-a}$ into final equation?

Comment: You are having a too formal approach to this. Geometrically $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ is the area under the curve $f(x)\,.$ As you said: the average $\bar{f}$ is the height of a rectangle with base $[a,b]$ that has the same area. In the case of a discrete sum $T$ is the constant amount you add up $n$ times to have the same sum as over the $f(x_i)\,.$